# Cannot display todos in react-redux (property map undefined)?

Tags: redux

I am trying to learn Redux by creating my own todo app without the flairs in Redux' official [todo app example](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/todos). I am having trouble displaying my todos list as I am getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`.

The repo can be found [here](https://github.com/IggHub/understanding-redux). It is fairly lightweight (less components than Redux' todo-app).

This is the part that I have trouble with:

```
/src/components/TodoList.js

import React from 'react';

const TodoList = ({todos}) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {todos.map(todo =>
        <li key={todo.id}>{todo.text}</li>
      )}
    </ul>
  )
}

export default TodoList;
```

I also use `connect` on my `ViewTodoList.js` containers. If I understand it correctly, by doing this I should populate my `todos` with the store states:

```
/containers/ViewTodoList.js

import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import TodoList from '../components/TodoList';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  todos: state.todos
}

const ViewTodoList = connect(
  mapStateToProps
)(TodoList)

export default ViewTodoList;
```

I am pretty sure my Redux store has the correct state. The AddTodo can be found [here](https://github.com/IggHub/understanding-redux/blob/master/src/components/AddTodo.js).

However, for some reason `TodoList` component inside `components/TodoList.js` is not receiving the todos states inside as `{todos}`. I think I might have made some mistake here.

How can I properly display all `todos` state inside `TodoList`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to return the value in your `mapStateToProps`. It should be:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  todos: state.todos,
});
```

Comment: Oh gosh, can't believe I did that. Thanks! By the way, I though I knew my ES6 arrow function but apparently I did not. Off topic, but do you know why adding that parentheses solved it?

Comment: It's because curly braces alone define the function body, so basically what you had previously was similar to having a function with just an expression in it.
When you add parentheses around the curly braces they simply become the object you return (so in short, parentheses are like a shortcut for `return`).

Comment: Thanks! Haha, I just found this too: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions. First part of the page says it all. Thanks for the help again :)